# How to associate NetBeans IDE with certain file extensions?

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor

For any other program I would right click on the file >> Open With >> Choose Default Program, and then I would browse and find the program and then it would appear on the list and I would click it and make sure the "Always use this program to open this kind of file" option is checked and hit ok.

However, for netbeans after I find the netbeans exe launcher file and go back to the screen where it should then be an option to select, it doesn't show up. So I can't associate any file types with netbeans.

You can imagine how frustrating it is to have to open netbeans first and then drag and drop the file I want to work on. I can never double click and start working and I work with script and html files all day.

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 11):

Just found the solution.

Open Regedit (start->run->regedit)

> Navigate to "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
>
> Navigate to "Applications"
>
> Navigate to "netbeans.exe"

Expand the subfolder: **"shell"** and then the subfolder **"open"**
Then click on the final folder named **"command"**.

In the right hand side you will see a (Default) key you need to **"Modify"** by right clicking.

Change the location of the file to your new version of Netbeans.. Mine was pointing to the 7.0 version, and now I have 7.1beta so it was broken.

I changed mine too :

> "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1 Beta\bin\netbeans.exe" "%1"  (with the quotes)

Now Netbeans should show up in the file associations list.

Thanks and good luck

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me. What did help in my case was deleting the whole key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Applications/netbeans.exe/` from Windows registry.

Now after selecting  `netbeans.exe` in `Choose Default Program` dialogue Netbeans properly appears in a list of programs and I can make it a default PHP "opener".

My solution was inspired by comment to [this Netbeans bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208489#c3)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an windows 7 question. Anyways, I will go to Start-> default Programs and then click on Associate file type or protocol with a program.

Comment: tried that, the same issue as I mentioned with right clicking. This area in windows 7 prompts me to choose the exe, when I do it doesn't make it show up on the list. It does so for every other program but not netbeans. So I can't associate it from even here.

Comment: I am sorry to hear. I can only think of registry corruption. I will try to fix my registry using any one of the registry cleaners.(after taking back up of course).

Answer (score 0):

The Default Programs control panel does not seem to offer the complete ability to edit file type associations. For example, you might not want to change an HTML file from opening by default in a browser, but you'd like to add an Edit function that opens in NetBeans.

The [Types](http://izt.name/apps/types) app, however, supports the full-featured associations editing you're used to from Windows XP, et.al.